проблема с контроллерами во VIEW при POST запросе с разных форм на разные контроллеры
Есть два контроллера прописанных в urls.py в приложении.



Вот они во view.py



И html файл где есть две формы, каждой форме я задал путь к своему контроллеру один из них с атрибутом action="{% url 'qury:index' %}", другой {% url 'qury:choise1' %}



Проблема в том, что POST запрос от второй формы принимает первый контроллер index(), там принимается POST запрос, дальше переменная в которую мы записали данные с POST не проходит валидацию и идет на else. А второй контроллер, который и должен был принять этот POST запрос ничего не принимает. Я в деббаг режиме проверял, ставил поинты во втором контроллере и при выборе формы и нажатии кнопки второй контроллер не принимает никаких POST запросов. В чем может быть проблема? Как это работает?
